# How to know the possible sets of n numbers?

Tags: php

I have a set of numbers `S = [1,2,3,4,5,6];` And I want to make all possible pairs among them but one thing to know the pair could not be repeat.

i have used this :-

```
$pairs = array('1','2','3','4','5','6');
$count = count($pairs);
$array = array();
for($i = 0;$i <= $count; $i++){
    for($j = 1; $j < $count; $j++){
        if($i < $j){
            $array[$i][] = $pairs[$i].','.$pairs[$j];
        }
    }
}
```

I want some thing like this :-

```
S = [1,2,3,4,5,6];

[1,2],[1,3],[1,4],[1,5],[1,6]
[2,3],[2,4],[2,5],[2,6]
[3,4],[3,5],[3,6]
[4,5],[4,6]
[5,6]
```

If anyone have any better suggestion please do reply as soon as possible.

Comment: Did you tried anything ?

Comment: how do you mean better suggestion? which suggestion is yours? :)

Answer (score 0):

Build a double nested `foreach` loop over your array, build your pairs and check if you already got them.

Pseudocode:

```
pairs = []
foreach(entry in array) {
    foreach(entry2 in array) {
        pair = [entry, entry2]
        if(!alreadyexists(pair in pairs) {
            add(pair to pairs)
        }
    }
}
havefun()
```

Btw: You won't get hurt if you try something yourself, this problem is rather trivial.